# Can't send mail in AWS centos docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, centos, docker-compose, amazon-ses

I have an AWS EC2 instance with Centos. I have configured the mail server with SES and mails can be sent from the host machine but when I try to send the mail from a container built from docker(Alpine) it cannot be sent. Host for the SMTP for the web application is given as AWS smtp east 2 endpoint.Mail even is triggred using Javax mail package inside the container.

Comment: Did you map the ports correctly from the container

Comment: Which port are you talking about?

Comment: Any error or anything? Also can you telnet to your SMTP host at 25 from inside the container?

Comment: Yes can telnet.